# Non-ASCII characters - conversion from std::string to char*

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, type-conversion, non-ascii-characters

I have a string with non-ASCII characters, for example `std::string word ("żółć");` or `std::string word ("łyżwy");`
I need to convert it properly to `const char *` in order to call `system(my_String_As_A_Const_Char_Pointer);`

I'm working on Linux.

How can I do it?

Comment: `word.c_str()` might work

Comment: `c_str()` gives you a `const char*`. Or is your question about encoding? In which case you need to be clear about what encoding you are using, and what encoding `system` needs. So, tell us more about encodings.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem was in other place, which isin't related to the question. `c_str()` works fine.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you ask a question and concentrate on non-ASCII characters, and then accept an answer that ignores that aspect. If encoding is not an issue for you, then you should ask how to get a `const char*` from a `std::string`. A trivial question that has been asked a million times already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) member function. It will return a `const char *` that can be used in functions that accept that type of argument. Here's an example:

```
int main(int, char*[]) {
    std::string word("żółć");
    const char* x = word.c_str();
    std::cout << x;
}
```

And [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31d77513f73fa7cf)'s a live example.

Answer (score 1):

With these conversions the only thing to care about is mixing wide chars with normal chars (which fails horribly). You are using a std:string, so c_str() is fine for pulling out a const char* to pass to some other library call.

Comment: So long as the encodings match.